# Are Ghosts a type of organism or Are they soul of human beings who are dead?

Tags: ghosts

What does Hinduism say about ghosts ?
Are ghosts a type of organism like - Human, Animal, Asur , Pisach, Devta etc or Are ghosts just soul of human beings who are dead ?

What are details about ghost ?